# Copy elements from queue to stack

Tags: c++, sorting, data-structures

I want to write a code that copies queue elements in to a stack, and this copied elements should be sorted in the stack.
i've written the code below:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n,x;
    queue<int> q;
    stack<int> s;
    cin >> n;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin >> x;
        q.push(x);
    }
    while(!q.empty()){
        if(s.empty()){
            s.push(q.front());
            q.pop();
        }
        else{
            if(q.front()>=s.top()){
                s.push(q.front());
                q.pop();
            }
            else{
                while(q.front()<s.top() && !s.empty()){
                    q.push(s.top());
                    s.pop();                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
    while(!s.empty()){
        cout << s.top() << " ";
        s.pop();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but for some test cases like:3 1 2 3,the code does not seem to work.
please help me to figure out the problem with my code.

Comment: stacks really aren't meant to be sorted.  Are you sure you don't need a `std::set`?  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: is this some kind of exercise? If there are some additional requirements you should mention them. If you just need values for the queue sorted, there are easier ways to do that

Comment: yes this is an exercise and it just siad that copy the elements of a queue into a stack such that finally the elements in the stack are sorted

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to have a logic error in your inner `while` loop. You test `s.top()` before you test for `s.empty()`, which is the wrong order. `s.top()` is invalid if `s.empty()` is true. However, the exercise can be resolved relatively easily as described below.

You can retrieve the underlying container of a container adapter using the following helper:

```
template <class ADAPTER>
typename ADAPTER::container_type & get_container (ADAPTER &a)
{
    struct hack : ADAPTER {
        static typename ADAPTER::container_type & get (ADAPTER &a) {
            return a.*&hack::c;
        }
    };
    return hack::get(a);
}
```

Then, after populating the queue, you can copy the contents directly to the stack's underlying container, and sort it.

```
auto &qc = get_container(q);
auto &sc = get_container(s);
sc.assign(qc.begin(), qc.end());
std::sort(sc.begin(), sc.end());
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do what is essentially a selection sort: go through the queue N times, each time selecting the largest element to push onto the stack. The general idea is:

```
queue = queue containing items
stack = new empty stack
while queue.count > 0
    // push the first item from the queue onto the stack
    stack.push(queue.pop())
    count = queue.count
    // for each item remaining in the queue
    for (i = 0; i < queue.count; ++i)
        // if the item from the queue is larger than what's on the stack,
        // then remove the item from the stack and put it back in
        // the queue. And put the item from the queue onto the stack.
        if (queue.peek() > stack.peek())
            queue.push(stack.pop())
            stack.push(queue.pop())
```

Comment: If this is the technique you propose, I think it better to pop the queue elements into a priority queue, and then pop the elements out of the priority queue into the stack.

Comment: @jxh: Yes, there are many more efficient ways to do this. I think the point of the exercise is to use only a queue and a stack: no priority queue, no sorting libraries, etc.